# When and where to use catch with asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, try-catch

This is more of a generic question to do with asynchronous functions rather than a specific issue I am having.

When I create an asynchronous function using 'try' I also use 'catch' to catch any errors. When I then use this function I might want to use '.then'. At this point, I often use '.catch' as well but do I need to? Should I use catch on the function itself as well as when I invoke the function?

For example, consider a simple asynchronous function such as:

```
async function getData(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Something bad happened!');
    }
    const data = await response.text();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error);
  }
}
```

And then you invoke the function and do something with the data:

```
getData('https://myurl.com')
  .then(data => document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = data)
  .catch(error => console.warn(error));
```

Would the above example be considered 'correct' or should the catch when using the function be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things you should keep in mind:

1. `try{} catch(){}` may be necessary if a function is able to cause an error, do a side effect like logging, or re-throw a more meaningful error.
   Say for example, The `fetch` url-end point is wrong i-e `404 error` or we have a error right in our JSON. So we much handle such situations. That's where in our `async` function `try-catch` does come handly.
2. Using `try, catch` at the top level. This will make sure that all our fetch calls within `async` function are handled properly.
3. `then. catch` from Promise cannot catch the `throw new Error`.
4. Coming to **Part B** of your Question. We are using  `then` block after  function because:

> Every Async function returns a promise no matter what. Even when
> nothing is returned from an Async-Function it still returns promise

In your case, `throw new Error('Something bad happened!');` is caught in the `catch` block below. Let's take a closer look.

```js
async function getData(expectedResult) {
 try {
    const response = await fakeFetchData(1000, expectedResult);
    if (response === 0) {
      throw new Error('Something bad happened!');
    }
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Oops: " + error);
  }
}

function fakeFetchData(ms, expectedResult){
 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(expectedResult), ms))
}

getData(1).then(d => console.log(d));
getData(0).then(d => console.log(d));
```

If `expectedResult <> 0`, it's fine. Otherwise, It'll log msg like below

[image]